# How to make a Session timer that disables a button

Tags: php, html

```php
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:<br>
    <input type="text" name="caption" id="basicInput" placeholder="Enter email"><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the code i made to upload an image. Now, how can I set a `Session` timer for the user after uploading the images, so when they have already upload the images, the button will be disabled for like **2 minutes** so they can't upload again after *2 minutes*. After *2 minutes* since they last uploaded, the button will back again.

if the timer 0 it will show

```php
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

and when they submitted the files the button will be disabled

```php
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" disabled="disable">
```

Comment: You have several options. Are you willing to use javascript, JQuery, or MySql?

Comment: i want to use javascript or maybe css if possible